# jquery does not link to html

Tags: jquery, html, css, eclipse

I am very new to HTML and JQuery,however i have written a html file and have added a jquery reference to that in eclipse. Both the files (html and js) are at same location in eclipse. When i run the HTML, i expect to see the jquery functions in the output which does not show up, only the HTML output is seen. Why is this happening? Is there any other way i can see the animation i have put in through JQuery or my linking is an issue?  Below are my HTML and JS files.

## test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Behold!</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="menu">
            <h3>jQuery</h3>
            <div>
                <p>jQuery is a JavaScript library that makes your websites look absolutely stunning.</p>
            </div>
            <h3>jQuery UI</h3>
            <div>
                <p>jQuery UI includes even more jQuery goodness!</p>
            </div>
            <h3>JavaScript</h3>
            <div>
                <p>JavaScript is a programming language used in web browsers, and it's what powers jQuery and jQuery UI. You can learn about JavaScript in the <a href="http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript" target="blank" style="text-decoration:none; color:#F39814">JavaScript track</a> here on Codecademy.</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js file:
-============

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#menu").accordion({collapsible: true, active: false});
});
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using jQuery UI, you also need to load the jQuery lib. Add this to your references:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">
```

Answer (score 2):

include jquery(+ *ui*) before including `script.js`

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need your

jquery first 
jqueryui second 
custom script after

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
```

as well as @tymeJV suggests you need to add the base jquery libary

Answer (score 0):

If you're building this web page in a local environment, this doesn't work:

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">`

You need to add your script like this:

`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js">`

notice the **http:** before `//ajax`